# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\{\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c} -\sqrt{px^2 + qx + r}~\right\}=\frac{b-q}{2\sqrt a}$

Tags: limits, radicals

Prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\{\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c} -\sqrt{px^2 + qx + r}~ \right\}
= \frac{b-q}{2\sqrt a}$$

For $ a=p$

Do you know this formula?
How to prove this?

Comment: Why? How to understand it?

Comment: Hint: treat this as a fraction with denominator $1$. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} + \sqrt{ax^2+qx+r}$ and simplify...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $a=p$,$$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}-\sqrt{px^2+qx+r}=\frac{(ax^2+bx+c)-(px^2+qx+r)}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+\sqrt{px^2+qx+r}}\sim\frac{(b-q)x}{(\sqrt a+\sqrt p)x}.$$

Comment: Is this formula commonly used? Or we multiple it by its conjugate?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: you are answering yourself.

Comment: Why i didnt see this formula in English websites?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: are you serious ?

Comment: Yes. Can you give me one websites having this formula?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: be specific about which formula.

Comment: The b-q/2$\sqrt a$ formula?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: come on, this is an exercise making you use limit computation techniques. The formula has no specific use in itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you know already derivatives then you can calculate this limit as follows in a very convenient way:

- Set $x = \frac{1}{t}$ and consider $t\to 0^+$:

\begin{eqnarray*}\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c} -\sqrt{ax^2 + qx + r} 
& \stackrel{x = \frac{1}{t}}{=} & \frac{\overbrace{\sqrt{a + bt + ct^2}}^{f(t):=} - \overbrace{\sqrt{a + qt + rt^2}}^{g(t):=}}{t} \\
& = & \frac{\sqrt{a + bt + ct^2} -\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{a}- \sqrt{a + qt + rt^2}}{t} \\
& \stackrel{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} & f'(0) -g'(0) \\
& = & \frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}} - \frac{q}{2\sqrt{a}}
\end{eqnarray*}